# Typing direction on input with mask

Tags: javascript, jquery, masking, maskedinput

I need to reproduce the behavior of [jQuery-Mask-Plugin](http://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/) and its `reverse: true` option, however the application heavily use the [digitalBush/jquery.maskedinput](https://github.com/digitalBush/jquery.maskedinput) library.

Already tried many hacks and still no success.

Using the `dir="rtl"` doesn't solve the problem at all.

The mask I'm trying to apply is: `99999999-9` having the number `0` as placeholder.

There is something else to try to implement the `reverse: true` behavior with [digitalBush/jquery.maskedinput](https://github.com/digitalBush/jquery.maskedinput) library?

Answer (score 0):

This only happens to devices with auto correct. Try using type="tel" for input types and there should latest updated input mask files to download. Also try autoComplete="off"